# How to select a control element from `print_control_identifiers` in `pywinauto`?

Tags: python, pywinauto

When using `pywinauto` with an application I can print out the control identifiers uwing the method `print_control_identifiers`. An example output is as follows:

```
   |    |    |    | ListItem - '02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure'    (L599, T1033, R1756, B1050)
   |    |    |    | ['02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure', 'ListItem3', '02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structureListItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure", control_type="ListItem")
```

I assume this is a "ListItem".

- But what do the different elements mean?
- What does "L599" mean? What "T1033"? What "R1756"? What "B1050"?
- What do the elements in that second row mean? (`['02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure', 'ListItem3', '02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structureListItem']`)?
- What does the last line (`child_element`) mean?
- Where is this documented?
- How can I select for example this element when I have the app window as `dialog`?

Answer (score 0):

This output

```
 ListItem - '02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure'    (L599, T1033, R1756, B1050)
   |    |    |    | ['02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure', 'ListItem3', '02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structureListItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure", control_type="ListItem")
```

seems to have the following meaning:

### First row

```
ListItem - '02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure'    (L599, T1033, R1756, B1050)
```

The control element is of

- type `ListItem`
- with the text `02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure`
- graphically located in a rectangle with the coordinates x=599 to 1758 and y=1033 to 1050

### Second row

```
['02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure', 'ListItem3', '02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structureListItem']
```

This is a list of names for this control, created by the function [get_control_names](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findbestmatch.html?highlight=get_control_names#pywinauto.findbestmatch.get_control_names).

### Third row

```
child_window(title="02.05.2023 11:31:53 - Retrieved tree structure", control_type="ListItem")
```

This seems to show a list on how to identify the element. The text `child_window` is always the same, and it can contain

- `title`: The control text (same as in first row)
- `control_type`: The type of the control (about the same as used in the first row)
- `automation_id` (optional): The automation ID if the element has one
- `control_type` (optional): The  .NET type of the control  if the element has one

Answer (score 0):

It depends which backend you use (`"uia"` or `"win32"`, I guess "uia"). There is a [Controls Reference](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/code.html#controls-reference) section in `Main User Modules` page.

You can find modules with `"uia"` in the name (`uiawrapper`, `uia_controls`), go to the link and find for `"ListItem"` (you will find [ListItemWrapper](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.html#pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.ListViewWrapper) for example).